# Loop a script and upload a file every 5 minutes

Tags: python, ftp, upload

I have created this script to upload a text file with python, but I want now to modify this script to upload this file every 5 minutes. How can I do this?

```html
import ftplib
import win32api
import os

sftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.microsoft.com','test','test') # Connect
sftp.cwd("test")

fp = open('test.txt','rb') # file to send
sftp.storbinary('test.txt', fp) # Send the file

fp.close() # Close file and FTP
sftp.quit()
```

Comment: Use cron http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/

Answer (score -1):

Python has `sched` [module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sched.html) for event scheduling.

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def do_something(sc): 
    print "Doing stuff..."
    # scheduling calls
    s.enter(300, 1, do_something, (sc,))

# initial call to function
s.enter(60, 1, do_something, (s,))  # (delay, priority, action, argument)
s.run()
```